# Местоимение и другие части речи

Tags: местоимение

Как отличить местоимение от других частей речи?

Comment: Не могли бы вы привести примеры, где есть такие трудности?

Answer (score 2):

**Местоимения соотносятся с существительными, прилагательными, числительными** по своим лексико-грамматическим значениям, **поэтому по форме их не всегда можно различить** (кто, какой, сколько, который, когда - местоименные существительное, прилагательное, числительное и наречие).

Соответственно, надо знать **классификацию местоимений (9 разрядов),** а она основана **на семантическом принципе** (личные, вопросительные, отрицательные, указательные, определительные, притяжательные и др.)

Местоимения у**казывают на признак, предмет, количество,**  их значение абстрактно, обобщенно  и приобретает конкретность только в тексте.

**В качестве примера можно привести счетно-местоименное слово один,** которое может быть не только числительным, но и прилагательным и местоимением.

ПРИЛАГАТЕЛЬНОЕ: 
Постепенно  диалекты слились в один язык (единый, целостный). Не оставляйте детей одних (без взрослых).

МЕСТОИМЕНИЕ: 
Мы с другом живем в одном доме  – том же самом.
Один красив, другой умен – указание на предмет из ряда   сходных предметов.
Повесть Салтыкова-Щедрина «История одного города»  – какого-то, некого, неопределенное местоимение.

Answer (score 1):

Главное отличие местоимений то, что это  самостоятельная часть речи, которая **указывает** на предметы, признаки, количество, но не **называет** их.

Разряды местоимений нужно выучить,тогда и путать с другими частями речи не будете.

Таблица разрядов местоимений русского языка

1.Личные

1 лицо – я, мы

2 лицо – ты, вы

3 лицо – он, она, оно, они (+ оне)

2.Возвратное    - себя

3.Притяжательные    1 лицо – мой, моя, мое, мои, наш, наша, наше, наши
2 лицо – твой, твоя, твое, твои, ваш, ваша, ваше, ваши
3 лицо – его, ее, их

4. Вопросительные   кто? что? какой? каков? чей? который? сколько? где? когда? куда? откуда? зачем?
5. Относительные    кто, что, какой, каков, чей, который, сколько, где, когда, куда, зачем
6. Указательные столько, этот, тот, такой, таков, тут, здесь, сюда, туда, оттуда, отсюда, тогда, поэтому, затем (+  сей, оный)
7. Определительные  весь, всякий, все, сам, самый, каждый, любой, другой, иной, всяческий, всюду, везде, всегда
8. Отрицательные    никто, ничто, некого, нечего, никакой, ничей
9. Неопределенные   некто, нечто, некий, некоторый, несколько, кое-кто, кое-где, кое-что, кое-куда, какой-либо, сколько-нибудь, куда-нибудь, зачем-нибудь, чей-либо.

**Или трудности в правописании? тоже - то же?**

Нужно видеть, где местоимение ТО с частицей ЖЕ (частицу можно опустить: Он делал то же, что вчера/то, что вчера). Союз тоже можно заменить другим союзом - также, и: Все пошли домой, он тоже пошёл (и он пошёл).